# pan to a specific part of an image

Tags: java, android, image

i am trying to do the folowing: set up a large image (larger than the screen or zoomed in at some point) and by swiping left or right to be able to focus the users view to a specific part on the image(pan and zoom to that point). similar to the map view when you center on some location (or zoom to). any pointers for how i can achieve this?

i saw the zoom and swipe examples JohnNick has provided and went to search further and i found these 2 tutorials for creating scroll and zoom on an image

[link Long-press and Scroll Large Images Using Low Level Events](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=36764)

[link Large Image Scrolling Using Low Level Touch Events](http://www.anddev.org/large_image_scrolling_using_low_level_touch_events-t11182.html)

but i still need a way to swipe to a specific part of an image. but now i have a dillema. as i read on there seem to be some issues with outOfMemoryException when working with large bitmaps, so my problem is: is it better to make the swipes as changing small bitmaps like the view transition example or is there a way to maybe only render the visible part of the image or something like that or maybe a map-like functionality ( dividing the image in ex. 8 parts and showing only the ones visible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click Here Example](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/) for Image Zoom and Pan

[Click Here Example](http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/16/how-to-implement-swipe-action-in-android/) for Image swiping